# How to design database tables (or hibernate entities)

Tags: hibernate, database-design

How should i design my tables in following scenario?

I have a **Parent** entity which can have multiple **child** entities, this is straightforward. Now i have another entity **external references** which is related to both that means a parent can have multiple **external references** and children can also have their own multiple **external references**. How should i design the table for **external references**, shall i keep all in one table or create two separate tables one for parent level references and another for children level references.

First approach by keeping all references in same table:

```
Parent - Parent_Id, other fields...
Child - Child_Id, Parent_Id (Foreign key to parent), other fields...
External Reference - Ref_Id, Parent_Id, Child_Id, other fields
```

But child_id can be null for parent level external reference therefore cannot make it foreign key. I have to maintain that foreign key in my code instead of DB constraint.

Second approach by keeping references in separate table:

```
Parent - Parent_Id, other fields...
Child - Child_Id, Parent_Id (Foreign key to parent), other fields...
Parent External Reference - Ref_Id, Parent_Id, other fields
Child External Reference - Ref_Id, Child_Id, other fields
```

If a user needs both level of references then has to look into two tables.

what is the best way to achieve this so i can keep all references in one place and also build FK relationships between them.

Comment: Generally, there are enough differences in a parent external reference and a child external reference that they should be two separate tables.  However, your specific needs might be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dilemma is a textbook example of when you should use an [association with a join table](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-12m) (we can call it a third approach :), but it should be the first really ).

That way you will not have the two tables for the one entity nor will you have the foreign key issue you've mentioned. Consider your two approaches in a case where more entities would be associated with the `ExternalReference`. Join table is the most future proof, and scalable approach in your situation